# How to get user tweets on Twitter on particular topic using Tweepy package in Python

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy

Suppose user 'ABCD' has tweeted on topic, how to find the comments for that tweet ?
I am using tweepy to get twitter data.

It will also be good, If it possible using any other python packages.

Code for the following is:

```
Import tweepy 
consumer_key = "" 
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)`  # This is authentication process.

new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name ='ABCD',count=20) # Code to download 20 timelines for user 'ABCD'
```

Till here i can get 20 timelines from user ABCD.

Q: How to get tweets for each timeline.

Thanks.

Comment: api = tweepy.API(auth) 
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

# Here I am getting timeline for that particular user. Next I want to get the sub tweets for that all  timelines.

From here I don't know how to proceed .

Comment: Add it to the question.

Comment: Added coding part in question, thanks.

Comment: didn't get any answer yet?